# In C++, the char variables belong to which character set, source or execution character set?

Tags: c++, char, set, character

C++11 §3.9.1
Objects declared as characters (char) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation’s basic character set.

Which character set does the implementation’s basic character set indicate? Basic source or execution character set?

Comment: The environment the compiler targets. If you target a PDP-11 you'll have 6-bit chars with the EBDCDIC character set for character literals. If you target Linux or Windows you'll probably have 8-bit chars with the ASCII character set for character literals.

Answer (score 0):

It technically is implementation defined.  In *practice*, `char` is 8 bits, either signed or unsigned by default.  Also in *practice*, US ASCII has formed the lowest common denominator across commonly available implementations you're likely to encounter.

That's just the lowest common denominator.  It ignores wide characters (ie. `wchar_t`) or other encodings beyond US ASCII.

The standard permits a wide range of implementations, including implementations where `char` is more than 8 bits.  They just aren't particularly common.

The other thing to note is that the source character set and execution character set need not match.  This is more likely to be the case for a cross compiler (such as for an embedded system) than for a self-hosted compiler.  Again, I don't think the standard ties the two together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But i'm not clear about the exact meaning of "implementation". Does it mean the implementation of C++ compiler?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what it means.  So if you pick up g++, or LLVM, or Microsoft's Visual C++, each of those is an implementation, for example.